# Does cross validation work with asymmetric loss functions?

Tags: cross-validation, loss-functions

Does cross validation work with an asymmetric loss function?

Comment: Could you define `asymmetric loss function`?

Comment: I find plenty of information by Googling *"asymmetric loss function" cross-validation*.

Comment: If by "work" you mean "it is an unbiased estimate of the expected generalization error/loss" then yes.

Comment: yes there are documents on google which define assymetrics functions but not to explain if bias variance decomposition hold.
Classical quadratic loss is symmetrics function. An assymetric function can be a quadratics loss function where positive prediction error are weighted differently than negative.
JohnRos, yes i mean expected generalization error.